# MongoDB push to nested array or insert new document

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, upsert

I'm using python's library for Mongo (pymongo) and my document looks like this:

```
{"vendor_id": 12, "title": "xyz", "price": 1499.0, "price_history": [{"date": "2019-12-01", "price": 1890.0}]}
```

I would like to push new price object to the "price_history" array if document with id=12 exists. If it doesn't I would create a new document that look the same as the pasted code.

It seems simple but I've checked multiple stackoverflow topics and mongodb docs and can't get it :/

I've come up with the code:

```
db.holidays.update_one(
            {"vendor_id": t["vendor_id"]},
            {"$push": {"price_history": t["price_history"][0]}},
            upsert=True
        )
```

but when document isn't found it inserts only vendor_id instead of entire document.

Any tips?
Thank you for spending your time on my problem.

Comment: When you say _...look the same as the pasted code above..._ does that mean the new document would have the same value for the `vendor_id`, `title`, `price`, and other fields?

Comment: yes, I meant it would just insert an entire document into collection. I'm reading about $setOnInsert - maybe that's the way I should go?

Comment: `$setOnInsert` is exactly the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$setOnInsert` to the rescue:

```
db.holidays.update(
   { "vendor_id": t["vendor_id" },   // Query parameter
   ,{                     // Update document
      "$push": {"price_history": t["price_history"][0]},
      "$setOnInsert": { everything else you want insert besides the push and the vendor_id
   }
   ,{ upsert: true }      // Options
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the record out into a dict and use standard python the manipulate. If you use `find_one()` and there's no match it will return `None`

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient()["testdatabase"]

# Data setup
db.testcollection.delete_many({})
template = {"vendor_id": 12, "title": "xyz", "price": 1499.0, "price_history": []}
data_setup = {"vendor_id": 12, "title": "xyz", "price": 1499.0,
              "price_history": [{"date": "2019-12-01", "price": 1890.0}]}
new_price = {"date": "2019-12-02", "price": 2000.0}

# Comment the next line out to see what happens if the record isn't present
db.testcollection.insert_one(data_setup)

record = db.testcollection.find_one({"vendor_id": 12})
if record is None:
    record = template

record['price_history'].append(new_price)
db.testcollection.replace_one({"vendor_id": 12}, record, upsert=True)

# Pretty up the record output
print(dumps(db.testcollection.find_one({}, {'_id': 0}), indent=4))
```

gives:

```
{
    "vendor_id": 12,
    "title": "xyz",
    "price": 1499.0,
    "price_history": [
        {
            "date": "2019-12-01",
            "price": 1890.0
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-02",
            "price": 2000.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I upvoted it however I think it's a bit too many requests to the db, wouldn't want to pay for this :D

Comment: It's only 2 calls once you strip out the setup. Make sure you add an index to `vendor_id` and it will be plenty fast unless you're making millions of updates.